# Objective C imageView with index with tableCell

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, imageview, cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    MovieSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:sightingAtIndex.titulo];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)sightingAtIndex.anyo]];

    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Batman.jpg"] ];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"300.jpg"]];


    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Batman.jpg"];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"300.jpg"];

    //[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)sightingAtIndex.date]];
    return cell;
}
```

I would like to add the first image to the first cell

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Batman.jpg"];
```

I would like to add the second image to the second cell

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"300.jpg"];
```

I should to do with atIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the index to know the cell where you are:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Batman.jpg"] ];
else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"300.jpg"];
```

That method is called ONCE for every cell it's going to be displayed, not once for all the cells.